# Does Terraria on Nintendo Switch support 4 player split-screen multiplayer?

Tags: terraria, nintendo-switch

I've looked at the Terraria official site, wiki, and many forums and see that XBox and Playstation support 4 player split-screen, but it is unclear if the Nintendo Switch supports 2 or 4 player split-screen.

Can anyone that owns this game on Nintendo Switch confirm if 4 player split-screen is possible?  Would love to play with my kids.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only supports up to 2 players for split-screen multiplayer.

Comment: That's what I suspected, thanks for the answer!